# How to draw a line along with some text in center in android?

Tags: android

I'm very new to android and I have to implement a view which looks something like:

```
-------------Some Text----------------------
```

I know that I can draw a line using `View` in my xml using the code like:

```
<View
android:layout_width="100dp"
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:background="#00ff00" />
```

this will end up in drawing the:

```
-----------------------
```

but after this I wish to place the text and again draw the other end of the line.

I tried but I get something like this:

```
----------------------
text
```

when I add some `TextView` after the `View` code.

Is that possible to do what I'm aiming for ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this will help you to get what you want. Giving weight to view is a key..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ff00" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#00ff00" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works fine, but I'd suggest using a `RelativeLayout`, because presumably this layout will have other elements too, which means you would have to nest the `LinearLayout`. That's bad for performance.

Comment: @j0ntech Yes that's true, but in relative layout you have to give fixed width. I don't know any other way to stretch lines.

Comment: @Hardik why fixed? If you set aligment from left to right it will strech whiew depend on parent width

Answer (score 2):

Try using `FrameLayout` for this cases or `RelativeLayout` to prevent deep view hierarchy and improve performance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff" >

<View
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#555" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:text="Hello world" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
        android:text="My Text" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:background="#00ff00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it works for you..

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest would probably just be to have a RelativeLayout or horizontal LinearLayout, half your line's width and create it as ;

View (50dp) - TextView - View (50dp)